# Deriving effective model without integrating out degrees of freedom in path integral formalism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral, models

In path integral formalism of quantum field theory (particle physics or condensed matter), one can in principle integrate out part of the degrees of freedom so as to attain an effective model comprising solely the system that we are interested in. Certainly, divergence sometimes occurs and one has to introduce various cutoff techniques. Anyway, this methodology seems to be quite powerful in many cases.

There are indeed plenty of means to get effective model. For instance, Brillouin–Wigner perturbation theory can be employed in showing the equivalence of a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ Heisenberg antiferromagnet and a half-filled Hubbard model in the $U\rightarrow\infty$ limit or the strong-coupling limit of an $SU(2)$ gauge theory coupled to fermions. Notwithstanding, the physical content of such looks considerably different from what one does along the path integral approach (at least not entailing limits of any parameter in Hamiltonian/Lagrangian) insofar as I understand.

I just wonder about any other distinct method for deriving effective model physically kinda similar to the path integral one. Because of the unambiguity of physics therein, I guess path integral mustn't be the unique way.

Comment: Your question looks very vague.

Comment: In the Hamiltonian formalism you can use [adiabatic elimination](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0610056) to integrate out fast degrees of freedom. Or if the irrelevant degrees of freedom live in one portion of a tensor product Hilbert space, you can use projection operator techniques and the partial trace to derive a [master equation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4666). These sort of approximations appear everywhere in physics and will not always start from a quantum path integral or Hamiltonian.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thanks. I think in general, the path integral approach doesn't require specific assumption (e.g. fast) on the DOFs to be integrated out. And partial trace is inequivalent, albeit resembling to the path integral one.

Comment: @huotuichang Actually, you can demonstrate that the partial trace over one portion of a tensor product Hilbert space corresponds exactly to integrating over those degrees of freedom in the Lagrangian formalism, see the textbook by Ulrich Weiss for example.